# assembler notation: sub -0x1(%bx,%di),%al

Tags: assembly, x86-16, disassembly, att, objdump

Anyone able to explain assembly notation? This is from objdump on linux:

```
ed:   2a 41 ff        sub    -0x1(%bx,%di),%al
```

What I know:

- the opcode is at position 0xed
- the opcode is 2a with arguments 41 ff
- is is a subtraction
- 0xff = -1

What I think I know:

- the destination is al (lower half of ax) (destinations are last, contrary to what I have read about AT&T notation)

What I don't know:

- what is that bit about -0x1(%bx,%di) ?

Comment: Use `objdump -Mintel` if you'd rather have Intel-syntax disassembly so the addressing-mode for the memory source operand would be `[bx+di - 1]`.

Comment: Whatever you read about AT&T syntax was wrong: destination *is* last in AT&T, vs. first in Intel syntax.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info for some info on AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 3):

> - the opcode is at position 0xed
> - is is a subtraction
> - 0xff = -1
> - the destination is al (lower half of ax)
> - destinations are last

That's correct

> the opcode is `2a` with arguments `41 ff`

This is also correct.

But please note that there are instructions where the opcode is not coded in one single byte.

As an example `sub $1,%bl` and `xor $2,%ch` are completely different instructions but the first byte is `80` (hexadecimal) in both instructions.

> contrary to what I have read about AT&T notation

Where did you read something different?

Destinations are on the left side of the comma in the Intel notation; they are on the right side of the comma in the AT&T notation.

> what is that bit about `-0x1(%bx,%di)` ?

In the Intel notation this would be written as: `[BX+DI-1]`

... so this means:

- Calculate BX+DI-1
- The result is interpreted as address relative to the (DS) segment
- Read the byte at this address in memory ("byte" because the destination is a byte)
- The data read is the "source" for the operation

**If you want to know what the byte `41` means:**

This is a bit more complicated:

A manual of an (older) x86 CPU describes:

```
SUB, source=memory, destination=register:
first byte:  0010101[w]
second byte: [mod][reg][r/m]
```

Looking up some tables in the same manual you find:

```
w=0:             Byte operation
w=0, reg=000:    Register = AL
mod=01, r/m=001: Memory address = DS:[BX+DI+(8 bit value)]
```

So we can calculate:

```
0010101[w]      = 0010101 0  = 00101010 = 2a (hex)
[mod][reg][r/m] = 01 000 001 = 01000001 = 41 (hex)
```

Comment: Which "older" manual are you quoting?  Intel's current manuals still show how 16-bit ModR/M bytes are encoded, because current CPUs still support 16-bit addressing modes.

Comment: @PeterCordes I used the Cyrix 686 manual. I used this manual because it is much shorter than current ones. Because I was not sure if newer manuals still use these abbreviations (e.g. "r/m") I mentioned that I took an older manual.

Comment: They do still use the `/r` and `r/m` notation.

Comment: Thank you to both of you. That clears it up quite well.